# Can I change icon in this case?

Tags: notepad++, icons, window

I have associated txt file and xml file with Notepad++ (both opened with it), so both of them  have the same icon with Notepad++. Is there any way to change the txt icon to a different icon than the xml icon?

Comment: What have you researched and/or tried so far? What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @CharlieRB I am using Window 7 64bit. I just can change notepad ++ icon. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. It explains how to use custom icons for file types but may require some registry editing.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/57455-file-extension-icon-change-default-icon.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is a program http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html witch manages file types. Find the xml file in program and right click it, select "Edit Selected File Type", then click on "..." besides Default Icon.